# Doing arithmetic operation using case and while loop in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
i="y"

echo "Enter the first value"
read a

echo "Enter the second value"
read b

while [$i="y"]
do
    echo "1.Addition"
    echo "2.Subtraction"
    echo "3.Multiplication"
    echo "4.Division"
    echo "Enter your choice:"

    read ch

    case $ch in

        sum=expr $a+$b | bc
        echo "Summation:" $sum;;

        sub=expr $a-$b | bc
        echo "Subtraction:" $sub;;

        mul=expr $a*$b | bc
        echo "Multiplication:" $mul;;

        div=expr $a/$b | bc -l 
        echo "Division:" $div;;

        *)echo "Invalid Choice"

    esac

    echo "Do You Want To Continue?"

    read i

    if(($i!="y")) ; then
        echo "Bye"
        exit0

    fi

done
```

I got error on line 17 why?
Is there any error?
Please help me out

```
ERRORS   

 line 24: syntax error near unexpected token $a+$b'   
 line 24:             sum=expr $a+$b | bc'
```

There are also problems with the case statement

Comment: Look up the syntax for `case` statements as this is completely wrong and is the reason you are getting errors

Answer (score 4):

**Typically, checking your broken shell code at http://shellcheck.net is sufficient to diagnose problems.**

Note: Some problems prevent full analysis up front. You may have to fix initial problems to reveal further ones.

Note that **many problems in your code stem from not using required spaces to satisfy syntax requirements** - spaces matter in `bash` programming (shell programming in general).

---

`while [$i="y"]` is **missing spaces**
 and should ultimately be `while [[ $i == "y" ]]`.

**`[` or `[[` must be followed by a space, and `]` or `]]` must be preceded by one** - using `[[ ... ]]` is preferred over `[ ... ]` in `bash`, because it is more robust and has more features.

**Operators** inside `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` conditionals **need spaces around them too**, as `bash` will otherwise perform *string* concatenation: `$i="y"` is interpreted as a *single* string and will (in the first iteration) result in string *literal* `y=y`.

---

Your **`case` statement is missing branch patterns** to describe when each branch should be executed, as @Jidder points out in a comment (we'll look at the broken code inside the branch quoted below later) (curiously, you did have *one* pattern in there, namely the one for the *else* branch, `*)`):

```sh
case $ch in

  1) # pattern followed by `)`describing when the branch should be executed
    sum=expr $a+$b | bc
    echo "Summation:" $sum;;

  2)
  # ...
```

---

**Missing command substitution** (`$(...)`) for capturing command output:

`sum=expr $a+$b | bc` will NOT capture the result of the pipeline in variable `$sum`, because you need [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) to capture a command's output (we'll look at how the specific command to be captured is broken later):

`sum=$(expr $a+$b | bc)`

---

**`expr` expects the elements of a calculation as *separate* arguments**, so it should be `expr "$a" + "$b"` (note the spaces).

More importantly, though: **you also pipe the result to `bc`, which is pointless**, because `expr` will have already performed the calculation.

You have 2 choices:

- Use just `expr` if *integer* calculations are sufficient. Preferably, **use bash's built-in [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html): `sum=$(( a + b ))`** (note that the `$` variable-name prefix is optional there, and even the spaces are optional, unlike with `[[ ... ]]`).
- Use just `bc` to also support calculations with decimal fractions: `sum=$(echo "$a + $b" | bc)` - at least in the case of division, `bc` is required.

---

`echo "Summation:" $sum` is, generally, more robustly written as `echo "Summation: $sum"`, because an *unquoted* variable reference is subject to various [shell expansions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), which can have unintended side-effects.

**As a rule of thumb, *double-quote* variable references** (either by themselves or as part of a larger string).

---

`(($i!="y"))` does not work as intended, because **`((...))` is used only for *arithmetic* evaluation**, not for string comparison; what you're looking for is `[[ $i != "y" ]]` (again, note the spaces).

However, since your `while` loop condition tests for the same, you can simply move the `echo "Bye"` and `exit 0` commands *outside* the loop. (Note that you were missing a space between `exit` and `0`).

---

If we put it all together (note, though, that there's still room for improvement):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the first value"
read a

echo "Enter the second value"
read b

i="y"
while [[ $i == "y" ]]
do

  echo "1.Addition"
  echo "2.Subtraction"
  echo "3.Multiplication"
  echo "4.Division"
  echo "Enter your choice:"

  read ch

  case $ch in

  1) 
    sum=$(echo "$a + $b" | bc)
    echo "Summation: $sum"
    ;;

  2)
    sub=$(echo "$a - $b" | bc)
    echo "Subtraction: $sub"
    ;;

  3)
    mul=$(echo "$a * $b" | bc)
    echo "Multiplication: $mul"
    ;;

  4)
    div=$(echo "$a / $b" | bc -l)
    echo "Division: $div"
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Invalid Choice"
    ;;

  esac

  echo "Do You Want To Continue?"

  read i

done

echo "Bye"
exit 0
```

Comment: This is also a programming assignment.  I prefer not spoon feeding nascent programmers.  Either they like it and learn how, or not.  Let them learn with hints, not with doing their work.

Comment: @BruceK: Fair point. However, since I won't be around to _keep_ spoon-feeding, there are 2 possible outcomes: (a) If the OP was indeed looking for someone to do their work for them, it worked in this case, but luck will run out eventually. (b) If the OP is indeed willing to learn, my answer contains (hopefully) helpful explanations and pointers to resources. As far as gimme-the-codez goes, this one is a less blatant case, as at least _some_ effort (though arguably not enough) was expended by the OP to answer their own question.